# Data Analysis and Forecasting In MATLAB

Tags: matlab, time-series, data-analysis, moving-average

I have a house price data with two rows, 1st: Date (monthly) and 2nd: Price of house, my data has the price record of houses from 1990-2012, I would like to predict the price of house in 2013 by calculating the moving average of the prices i have to forecast and predict the 2013 house price.Please any idea on how to carry out simple time series analysis (step-by-step)in MATLAB? I would appreciate sample codes.

Comment: I tried fitting in the matlab moving average (tsmovavg) syntax to find the moving average between my prices but got the error below; 
>> VO = tsmovavg (price, 's', length(price))
Error using tsmovavg>simplema (line 229)
Lag must be scalar greater than 0 or less than the number of observations.

Comment: Then why don't you post part of your code and the error you get to have the discussion starting from there.

Comment: Oh yeah sure i will take note of that! Thank you!

Comment: >> Q = ones (1,3)./3;
>> G = conv2(c1,Q,'same').'; 
>> Moving_average=conv2(c1,Q,'same').'; I tried finding the moving average of my price row (c1) but the results i am getting is invalid, Any suggestions please? This is exactly what i am trying to replicate in matlab. Thanks! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LLpQcVSeoQ